# matrix version of Rayleigh quotient

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $G$ be $m$ times $p$ matrix and $W$ be $m$ times $m$ symmetric positive definite matrix. Then, is the following true?

$G'WG \le \lambda_{max}(W)G'G$

where $\lambda_{max}(W)$ denotes the maximum eigenvalue of $W$.